# Slimming JSON messages down without deriving from `list`

Tags: python, json, flask, server

Consider a server generating JSON messages for a to-do list.

```
import json

class Action(object):
    def __init__(self, what, when):
        self.what = what
        self.when = when

class Actions(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.actions = []

    def insert(self, action):
        self.actions.append({'action': 'insert_todo',
                             'detail': {'what': action.what,
                                        'when': action.when}})

class Batch(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.urgent_actions = Actions()
        self.ordinary_actions = Actions()
        self.urgent_actions.insert(Action('tidy up', '8am'))

def jdefault(o):
    return o.__dict__

def output_json():
    batch = Batch()
    mystr = json.dumps(batch,
                       default=jdefault,
                       indent=4)
    print(mystr)

output_json()
```

This works fine, and we get the message:

```
{
    "urgent_actions": {
        "actions": [
            {
                "action": "insert_todo",
                "detail": {
                    "what": "tidy up",
                    "when": "8am"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "ordinary_actions": {
        "actions": []
    }
}
```

But repeating `actions` inside both priorities of actions and in each message is asking for some clean-up.

We can do that by deriving `Actions` from `list`:

```
class Actions(list):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        list.__init__(self, *args)

    def insert(self, action):
        self.append({'action': 'insert_todo',
                     'detail': {'what': action.what,
                                'when': action.when}})
```

And we get indeed the slimmer JSON message:

```
{
    "urgent_actions": [
        {
            "action": "insert_todo",
            "detail": {
                "what": "8am",
                "when": "8am"
            }
        }
    ],
    "ordinary_actions": []
}
```

Yet,
[deriving](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44418393/704972)
[from](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11703577/704972)
[list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40361189/704972)
[is](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9432844/704972)
[far](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3488283/704972)
[from](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25328940/704972)
the best idea.

What other (idiomatic) way would you use to get the slimmer message without deriving from `list`?

The messages are to be sent through Flask, in case you'd also like to critique the use of `json.dumps`.

Comment: Make a single list of actions and some of them (or all of them) have a Boolean "urgent" attribute?

Comment: @Tomalak We could get rid of `Batch` altogether as you suggest. The 'urgent attribute' is here a placeholder for features. That is a separate issue from `Actions`. What might be a good idea for avoiding the inheritance from `list`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than change the classes, you could delegate defining the structure of the json to the `jdefault` function.

```
def jdefault(o):
    if isinstance(o, Batch):
        return o.__dict__
    if isinstance(o, Actions):
        return o.actions
    raise TypeError("Object of type {} is not JSON serializable".format(type(o)))
```

Which generates the desired output:

```
{
    "urgent_actions": [
        {
            "action": "insert_todo",
            "detail": {
                "what": "tidy up",
                "when": "8am"
            }
        }
    ],
    "ordinary_actions": []
}
```

This way you separate the concerns of your objects' structure and serialisation.